# element a conjugate to element b

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Definition:
>
> Two elements a,b $\in$ G are conjugates if there exists some element g $\in$ G s.t $b=g^{-1}ag$

$\space$

> Definition:
>
> Suppose g, h $\in G$.
> We call the element $h^{g}=g^{-1}hg$ the conjugate of h by g.

In a theorem from my notes, I see "**g is conjugate to h** IFF g and h have the same cycle structure"

What does the highlighted bold means? Is this an alternate rewording of a familiar definition? Perhaps, the first definition? Can someone confirm please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the highlighted bold is equivalent to the first definition, namely: "**$g$ and $h$ are conjugates**".

Notice that if $g$ is conjugate to $h$, then $h$ is conjugate to $g$. That is, the "is conjugate to" relation is symmetric, so the first definition is unambiguous. Indeed:
\begin{align*}
\exists g \in G \text{ such that } b = g^{-1}ag
&\iff \exists g \in G \text{ such that } a = gbg^{-1} \\
&\iff \exists h \in G \text{ such that } a = h^{-1}bh \\
\end{align*}
where in the last line we take $h = g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

"$g$ is conjugate to $h$" means precisely that $g,h$ are conjugates according to your first definition.